# Is it possible to create a vector logo with photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am attempting to create a logo for a website and I have read that it is a good idea to create a vector logo. Can I do this with photoshop? Any tutorials and or books that you would recommend that I purchase?

Comment: You already have your answer but I recommend also to take a look at Sketch, I really like this piece of software!

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop is capable of creating vector images. But as mikemcmac said, Illustrator is a better tool for this.

However, if the logo is simple and all you have is Photoshop, you can use Photoshop's vector tools to make it work. Better that than to make a pixel-based logo.